# Getting values back from nested loops

Tags: python

I have two dictionaries that I want to evaluate, return specific data from to perform other functions and finally to update as a save file for future runs.

Data looks like this:

```
save_file = {
      "UK": {
            "search": "tag:\"uk\"",
            "priority": 10,
            "asset_ids": [200] #s
      },
      "Windows": {
            "search": "tag:\"windows*\"",
            "priority": 8,
            "asset_ids": [300]
      },
      "Web Servers": {
            "search": "tag:\"web\"",
            "priority": 7,
            "asset_ids": []
      }
}
    
new_data = {
      "UK": {
            "search": "tag:\"uk\"",
            "priority": 10,
            "asset_ids": [100, 200] #n
      },
      "Windows": {
            "search": "tag:\"windows*\"",
            "priority": 8,
            "asset_ids": []
      },
      "Web Servers": {
            "search": "tag:\"web\"",
            "priority": 7,
            "asset_ids": []
      }
}
```

If a new asset ID shows up (e.g. 100) I need to compare with the save_file and return  it if it's not in the save file.
That currently looks like this:

```
for r in new_data:
    for n in new_data[r]['asset_ids']:
        print ('testing', n)
        for a in save_file:
            if n not in save_file[a]['asset_ids']:
                print ('not found in this loop', n)
            else:
                print ('found!', n)
```

Output:

```
testing 100
not found in this loop 100
not found in this loop 100
not found in this loop 100
not found in this loop 100
not found in this loop 100
not found in this loop 100
testing 200
found! 200
not found in this loop 200
not found in this loop 200
not found in this loop 200
not found in this loop 200
not found in this loop 200
```

While I'm happy I'm testing the right thing at least, I'm stuck on how I should return that data back from the nested loops so I can say 'this asset is not in the save file'.

Comment: fit everything in a dict like `{"1": yourdata, "2" : ..}`

Comment: I don't understand what is your actual question. You seem to be able to find the value - but you're just printing it. If you want to save the value for later use either save it in a variable or wrap the code in a function and `return` the value

Answer (score 0):

Seems to me you just need to break when you found your value and add a `else` statement to your loop :

```
for r in new_data:
    for n in new_data[r]['asset_ids']:
        print ('testing', n)
        for a in save_file:
            if n in save_file[a]['asset_ids']:
                print ('found!', n)
                break
        else:
            print("This asset is not in the save file")
```

Comment: Awesome. I was experimenting with while statements but this does what I need.

Comment: Perfect ! If this solve your problem could you please mark your question as resolved ?